# How to make my blocks switch to another block when session was set?

Tags: 8, blocks

I have 2 header block, default 1 is the login form and the other block was for logout button. I want to make this two blocks switching after triggering the login button

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in code:

```
if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {}
```

Or in block layout by configuring the visibility of roles:

When the user has the following roles

- Anonymous user
- Authenticated user
- Administrator

The first block for anonymous users and the second block for authenticated users.

Comment: I see but my problem was i dont use roles, i make my own roles and i used  EXTERNAL REST API for manipulating the data. And also i thought its the same flow like session? i try this 

if (empty($sun) && empty($sid) || $sid == '' &&  $sun == '') {
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\modules\Form\LoginForm');
    return $form;
   }else{
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\modules\Form\rLogoutForm');
    return $form;
   }

the problem is i need to clear the cache to rebuild the blocks to work the switching.

Comment: In this case you have to add a cache context before you return $form: `$form['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'session';`